# Making android 'select all' option only to select custom content in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, textselection

Anyone ever been to this situation where you want to make the android 'select all' option to select custom content? Now 'select all' selects the whole page. I only want it to select one part of the page.
Any help will be appreciable.
please check the screenshot below attached

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this class where you do not want the selection

```
.noselection {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: I do want all fields to be selectable. But separately. Say, if I select one word and click 'select all' it should only select that particular paragraph. Anything I do to achieve this?